# How to hide all javadoc (phpdoc) blocks in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: php, eclipse, javadoc, zend-studio, phpdoc

I want to hide all phpdoc information. When I click to "-" as shown in the image below I can hide but I have to do it for each phpdoc block. Is there a way to hide all phpdoc information.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have it hidden by default by going to
**Window --> Preferences**
Go to **Java --> Editor --> Folding**
Select to hide comments by default. You may need to change **Java** to your language (php)

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Window menu and to preferences there are some folding options in there under the editor for the language you are using if I remember correctly. Check around in there, and you should be able to fold, or hide, comments.